# Will being very muscular (to the point that one is characterised as obese by BMI) increase blood pressure?

Tags: cardiology, blood-pressure

It is widely accepted that obesity/overweight (which I believe refers to people with a high amount of fat cells instead of bodybuilders who weigh a lot due to lots of muscle cells) have higher blood pressure due to various reasons e.g.["larger body mass increase resistance to flow", "increase insulin resistance that increases cholesterol and risk of blocked arteries", "more blood (i.e. plasma) is required to supply the larger body mass thus puts pressure on vascular system", "increased weight takes more pressure to move blood around the body" and etc.](https://www.sharecare.com/health/high-blood-pressure/what-causes-high-blood-pressure)

Therefore, based on the arguments above, is it fair to also say that muscular bodybuilders who are obese by BMI metric, have higher blood pressure?

Comment: May I ask why is this question downvoted? Is there something wrong with this question?

Comment: Perhaps it was downvoted because it's better suited to health or physical fitness sites.  Or because it can be answered with a simple Google search.  (The consensus from skimming a few articles suggests that while it's not a good idea to do serious weight training if you already have serious HBP, it doesn't cause it.)

Comment: Thanks for taking ur time. I've done some research on this topic but the answers come in the form of how "exercise or people with lots of fat cells thus are obese affect BP" rather as how "muscular people who are obese by bmi standard affect BP". Even then, the theories given as to why people with lots of fat cell have higher BP are somewhat skeptical, and the theories (e.g. more body mass thus require more blood plasma to deliver more O2) should translate to very muscular people who are obese by bmi metric.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! I’ve been studying the effects of BMI on blood pressure over the last four weeks. In my study, those with higher BMI’s did in fact have raised blood pressure in comparison to those in a healthy weight range. However, this was a controlled study where participants were selected and so this solely focused on individuals who were classed as overweight or obese due to excessive fat. Often, BMI isn’t an accurate way to measure body weight, for reasons such as muscular persons being classified as overweight or obese. HOWEVER! This is where it gets interesting, being fat puts strain on your heart, your heart must work harder to support your body. BUT, animal fats play a large part in raised blood pressure. The lipids from animal fats form deposits within your arteries causing a blockage. So would it be safe to say that those of a muscular build consume more animal fats to promote muscle growth? Maybe! Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello Emma. Can you please add some references to support your answer? Good references include peer-reviewed articles, books and websites of scientific organizations.